# How to require chunks in Webpack?

Tags: webpack

Is there a way to require chunk created in `require.ensure`? I want to preload some most used of them with `<link rel="prefetch" />` to reduce latency.

So I want to get something like:

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="1.e0d62ed2.chunk.js" />
<link rel="prefetch" href="named-chunk.4864883a.js" />
```